# calculating revenue churn using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

Say I have a pandas dataframe, df:

```
cust | year | revenue
1 | 2013 | 100
1 | 2013 | 50
2 | 2013 | 70
2 | 2015 | 10
3 | 2016 | 10
3 | 2019 | 65
...
```

I want to be able to calculate the revenue loss from a customer that stopped doing business. For example, since customer #1 stopped doing business after 2013, we would say there is a $50 churn in 2014.

I want to get the sum of all the churned revenue (lost revenue) by year. The output would be something like:

```
YEAR
2013 0
2014 150
2015 0
2016 10
2017 0
2018 0
2019 0
2020 65
```

My current logic is as follows: get revenue from the max year/latest transaction for each individual customer, and sum all those values, grouped by year.

Comment: Why is it 50 for customer 1 and not 150 since the revenue is for the same year: 2013.

Comment: @It_is_Chris you're right - i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been framed as to induce one to consider the "churn" as a binary condition: either a customer continues to do business with your company or not.
However, you still want to know how much money you will lose when a customer stops doing business with your company, which then changes the output from a binary to a numeric variable.

I have calculated the churn by customer year on year and then aggregated all changes in revenue per year for the whole company, which I think will solve your issue.

I've used this synthetic data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sets random seed
np.random.seed(42)

# Sample size
size= 10**3

# Creates customers series
unique_customers = np.arange(1, 51)

customers = [unique_customers[i] for i in
             np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(unique_customers), size=size)]

# Creates date series
unique_dates = pd.date_range(start="2013-01-01", end="2017-12-31", freq="D")

unique_years = unique_dates.year.unique()

dates = [unique_dates[i] for i in
         np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(unique_dates), size=size)]

# Creates revenues series
unique_revenues = [100, 50, 70, 10, 65]

revenue = [unique_revenues[i] for i in
           np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(unique_revenues), size=size)]

# Creates Pandas DataFrame
data = (pd.DataFrame({'Customer': customers,
                     'Date': dates,
                     'Revenue': revenue})
        .set_index('Date')
        .sort_index())

# Randomly sets customers revenues to zero
rem_customers = set([unique_customers[i] for i in
                     np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(unique_customers), size=10)])

for cust in rem_customers:
    rem_year = unique_years[np.random.randint(low=2, high=len(unique_years), size=1)].values[0]
    data.loc[(data.index.year >= rem_year) & (data['Customer'] == cust), "Revenue"] = np.nan
```

This is how the data set looks like:

```
            Customer  Revenue
Date                         
2013-01-01        36    100.0
2013-01-03         1     10.0
2013-01-03        47     50.0
2013-01-04        28     10.0
2013-01-04        25     65.0
```

I have deliberately set some customers' revenues to zero after a given date, to illustrate the problem.

You can use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to define the levels of aggregation, [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to calculate the lost revenue at the given level of aggregation and [`resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to change the time series frequency from daily to yearly, for instance.

```
# Calculates revenue by customer
revenue_by_customer = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='AS'),'Customer']).sum()

# Calculates the change in revenue by customer year on year
diff_revenue_by_customer = (
revenue_by_customer.groupby(['Customer'])
.diff(1)
.rename(columns={'Revenue':'Revenue_change'})
)

# Calculates total change in revenue year on year
diff_revenue_per_year = diff_revenue_by_customer.droplevel(1).resample('AS').sum()
```

Customer #40 has stopped doing business with the company after 2014 and here is how their records look:

```
revenue_by_customer.xs(40, level=1, drop_level=False)

>>                      Revenue
>> Date       Customer         
>> 2013-01-01 40          285.0
>> 2014-01-01 40          195.0
>> 2015-01-01 40            0.0
>> 2016-01-01 40            0.0
>> 2017-01-01 40            0.0

diff_revenue_by_customer.xs(40, level=1, drop_level=False)

>>                       Revenue_change
>> Date       Customer         
>> 2013-01-01 40            NaN
>> 2014-01-01 40          -90.0
>> 2015-01-01 40         -195.0
>> 2016-01-01 40            0.0
>> 2017-01-01 40            0.0
```

When we add up the change in revenue by year, this is the resulting table:

```
diff_revenue_per_year.head()

>>             Revenue_change
>> Date               
>> 2013-01-01      0.0
>> 2014-01-01  -2490.0
>> 2015-01-01   2255.0
>> 2016-01-01  -1545.0
>> 2017-01-01  -1305.0
```

You can also add up only the lost revenue year on year, with the following code:

```
lost_revenue_per_year = (
    diff_revenue_by_customer
    .loc[diff_revenue_by_customer['Revenue_change']<0]
    .droplevel(1)
    .resample('AS')
    .sum()
    .rename(columns={'Revenue_change':'Lost_revenue'})
    )

lost_revenue_per_year.head()

>>             Lost_revenue
>> Date                    
>> 2014-01-01       -4935.0
>> 2015-01-01       -2725.0
>> 2016-01-01       -4290.0
>> 2017-01-01       -3995.0
```